# Hide ----- comment in visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm not sure what are this lines and I don't know what to search about this. I pressed something in visual studio and this lines showed up and I don't know how to remove it.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlManifestReport" runat="server">
----<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptManifestReport" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
--------Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
--------WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="912px">
--------<LocalReport ReportPath="rdlc\rptManifestReport.rdlc">
--------</LocalReport>
----</rsweb:ReportViewer>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Type Ctrl-R, Ctrl-W Shows or hides spaces and tab marks

Comment: @TamilSelvan If that works, I suggest you put it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

The menu option `Edit / Advanced / View White Space` or `Ctrl-R/Ctrl-W` will show spaces and tabs